# get count and another values in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as
begin
    select count(*)t.TBarcode, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
    from Transaction_tbl t
    where TBarcode=@carid;
    declare @transid integer=null;
   select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
begin
return 1
end
end
```

I want to get count of T.TBarcode
while executing error coming like this:Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select **`count(*)t.TBarcode`**, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
    from Transaction_tbl t . the bold statement is place where you answer is incorrect. it not possible for `count(*)t.TBarcode` .

Add the following after where condition

```
group by t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate;
```

IF you want the sum of `t.paid` just don't put it in `group by` clause.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as
begin
    select count(t.TBarcode) as count, sum(t.Paid),t.Status,t.DelDate
    from Transaction_tbl t
    where TBarcode=@carid;

    group by t.status,t.DelDate

    declare @transid integer=null;
   select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
begin
return 1
end
end
```

Comment: sir,,that i know,,,i want to know how i can get count of (t.TBarcode)

Answer (score 0):

Try following store procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation] @carid nvarchar(100)=null
as
begin

    select sum(case when t.TBarcode is null then 0 else 1 end) as cnt, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
    from Transaction_tbl t
    where TBarcode=@carid
    group by t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate;

    declare @transid integer=null;

    select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
    if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
    begin
     return 1
    end
end
```

Comment: sir,,,this I tryed already..That time i am getting Error:Column 'Transaction_tbl.Paid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention group by close . we must have to use group by clause when we use any aggregate functions like count(*) , avg , min or max etc . Check it now . I modified the store procedure.

Comment: it s oke,,,,,so how i can re-write the stored procedure with group by clause

Comment: I already modified store procedure using group by clause . Check it  .

Comment: but,,,executing above stored procedure i am not getting count of Tbarcode..if the carid is not there ,,,then table is getting null,,,actully i want to show,,if the carid is not ther i want to get Tbarcode count is 0

Comment: you have to use case statement to calculate that type of count . I modified the store procedure again . check it .

Comment: still am getting empty table only,,,actullay my passing parameter(@carid) and TBarcode is same

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as
begin
    select count(t.TBarcode) as barcodeCount, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate
    from Transaction_tbl t
    where TBarcode=@carid;

    group by t.paid,t.status,t.DelDate

    declare @transid integer=null;
   select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid;
if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
begin
return 1
end
end
```